# Liferay 6.1 customizing role and permission for different user in document and media portlet

Tags: liferay, customization, portlet

I am new to liferay. I have one issue. I have 3 sub organizations (org A, B and C) each has each individual users. For exampla UA1, UB2, UC3 respectively.

Now I want to customize the permission of document and media portlet in such a way that UA1 can upload/ download his documents. But another User in Org A for example UA4 cannot access UA1's document. In the meanwhile Users UB2 and UC3 can see user UA1's document or add new document for her.

Can I achieve this my creating roles and permission? I have tried many combinations but it's not working.

How can I achieve this. Please do let me know. thanks

Comment: Just wondering, did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Here we have 2 cases
1. User of same organization can't view the image added by other user of same org.It can be achieved by creating an custom resource-action say (SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL) and manage it permission.
2.User of other organization can view the content can me manage by creating one role and define permission to it .